# How to add bundled products to the cart simultaneously with checkboxes in magento

Tags: magento

In Magento, I created a list of bundled products. In the frontend, along with each bundled product a checkbox is placed, so the user could select any number of bundled products with checkboxes, and add all of them in a cart simultaneously. 
I wanted to know how I would be able to add all the selected bundled products to the shopping cart in a bulk.

Please check the link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53435938/bundled-product-list.png

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that this is on the product detail page then the easiest way would be to use javascript, but without a screenshot and html its very to explain . Also take a look http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33997/

Comment: The bundled products are displayed on the product list page(list.phtml). Please check the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:
Use ajax to post items to cart.
Use a use custom controller to add multiple items to cart (magento allows to add related items but you can't specify qty)

Maybe look at http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-increase-magento-sales-with-one-simple-extension/ for inspiration on the module

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the out-of-the-box bundle product type?

There is a way to setup such a bundle so that all of the items are "required" when purchasing the bundle. It should work out-of-the-box and you shouldn't have to pass anything to the add-to-cart function other than the ID of the entire bundle.

What you will want to do is edit the bundle product to have a single selectable product for each bundled option. Be sure to set the user-defined quantity to "no". See attached screenshot.

[image: Magento Bundle Product.png]